# What's the Most Appropriate Type of Regression for this Problem?

Tags: statistics, regression, linear-regression, regression-analysis

I have a data set from two groups: firms that use AI and their costs and firms that don't use AI and their costs. Within both groups I have data about their specific costs, e.g. fixed costs, variable costs, etc.

I'm not sure if regression is the best way to do this, but I want to explore whether firms that use AI have lower costs. Any ideas on how I'd do this? Could I run OLS on both groups and just compare? The sample for firms that use AI is ~40 and ~100 for those that don't.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to do a two-sample t-test since you are comparing two populations on one variable and you would like to check if the means of the costs from both groups are equal. There are a few variants of the two-sample t-test based on whether you want to pool or not.

You probably want to use the null hypothesis:
$$H_0 : \mu_1 = \mu_2$$ where $\mu_1$ is the mean cost for the first population (those that use AI) and $\mu_2$ is the mean cost for the second population, and use an alternative hypothesis of:
$$\mu_1 < \mu_2$$ to see whether firms that use AI (population 1) have less cost.

For reference, [wikipedia article on t-tests](https://stattrek.com/statistics/dictionary.aspx?definition=two-sample%20t-test) or [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test).